# Hoover Dam Parking

Tags: planning, automobiles

Planning to drive to the Hoover Dam tomorrow and would not be surprised if it were busy base on high rental car activity.  Google indicates it is open at 9AM and I would like a parking spot.  Can I expect to find a parking spot if I arrive at 8:30AM?  If not, when is the time to arrive?

Comment: Did you ask your Dam guide? He's the one you are supposed to ask all your Dam questions to.

Comment: At 8:30 AM Saturday, there was plenty of parking in the garage (which provides covered parking: nice when it is 100+ degrees).  By 9AM it was plenty warm to walk outside, so arriving in the early AM is good if walking outside.

Answer (score 6):

I have been at the dam several times last year, and I always found a spot easily, even at lunch times.

However, not in the *lowest* parking area - behind the dam, the street winds up the hill, and has several more parking lots; the higher you get, the easier to park (and the further to walk back, maybe 1/4 mile from the last one). If walking doesn't shock you, you do not need to worry. At 8:30, you can probably even park in the lowest lot.